# HTML5 input syntax

Tags: html, html-input

I've been following the Angular2 tutorial https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html and found the following input element syntax (under the "Add a Hero" heading):

```
<input #heroName />
```

This is supposedly setting the `id` attribute of the `input` element, but I could not find this syntax in the HTML5 specification (https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0).

Can anyone explain this syntax?

Comment: It is angulars syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not referring to the element id of html5.
It's strictly related to angular2 and is a [Template reference variable](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars).

So, as said in the official documentation,

> The hash (#) prefix to "phone" means that we're defining a phone variable.

In your case is not "phone", but "heroName".